# Should the "tense" tag be always used for questions about tenses, even when there is a more specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions about tenses, there is a generic tag ([tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tense)), but there are also more specific tags, such as [past-tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-tense).

Should [tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tense) always be used for questions about tenses, even when a more specific tag can be used?

Comment: I think probably the generic tag *should* be linked as well as any more specific one if applicable.